管理者権限付きネットワークドライブの割り当てをタスクスケジューラで行う方法
管理者権限付きネットワークドライブの割り当てをタスクスケジューラで行うために方法を模索しているのですが、行き詰っています。どなたか解決方法をご存じでしたらご教示願います。
やりたいこと
PC(以下PC1とします)から自宅LAN内の別PC(以下PC2とします)上のドライブパスをネットワークドライブとして利用しようとしています。
その際、PC1で管理者権限つきで起動しているアプリケーションからもアクセスする必要があります。
毎回手動で実行するのは手間なので、タスクスケジューラにbatファイルの実行を設定して管理者権限でマウントを自動化したいと考えています。
実施したこと

下記batを作成してログオン時に実行するようタスクスケジューラに設定しました。

@echo off
if not “%~0″==”%~dp0.\%~nx0″ start /min cmd /c,”%~dp0.\%~nx0” %* & goto :eof

net use D: \\PC2\<Path_to_share>


タスクスケジューラの設定:

トリガー: ログオン時
操作: プログラムの開始: 上記batのpath
タスク実行時に使うユーザーアカウント: ログインユーザーと同じ
最上位の特権で実行するにチェック


PC1のネットワークドライブとしてD:に\\PC2\\<Path_to_share>を設定し、サインイン時に再接続するにチェックを入れました。

起きていること
D:にネットワークドライブが起動時にマウントされ、エクスプローラから参照可能な状態にはなっているのですが、管理者権限で開いたアプリケーションから当該のD:上のパスを開くとエラーとなります。
実施したことの2.に記載した設定は成功していますが、1.に記載した設定が上手く行っていないと思われます。
また、上記batを管理者権限で実行してもコマンドは正常に終了しましたと表示されるだけで問題は解決せず、管理者権限で実行したWindows Terminal上のPowerShellでnet use D: \\PC2\<Path_to_share>のコマンドを実行すると解決することを確認済みです。

何のための if 文かわかりませんが、 if 文が goto :eof になっているのではありませんか？、削除したら割り当てられるのでは？

念のために、実際に実行されるコマンドは echo on に変更して、コマンドプロンプトを立ち上げ、バッチファイルをドラッグして実行すればわかります。

if文はスタートアップ起動した際にコマンドプロンプトをフォアグラウンドで立ち上げず、最小化して起動するための文です。最初の2行はいずれもコメントアウトして試したものの、期待した結果は得られませんでした。

net use コマンドが実行されなかったということでしょうか？また、最小化して起動するということであれば、cmd.exe から引数としてstartコマンドで起動したらどうですか？

ダブルクォーテーションとして使われている文字が3種類(“,″,”)あってすべて全角だったので、すべて半角の " に変更したら動作しました。
バッチファイルを起動するためのコンソール画面は通常の大きさで表示されますが、net use を起動するコンソールは最小化になります。
net use コマンドは資格情報が要求されました。
下記のようにuserパラメータを追加するとパラメータなしでもドライブが割り当てられました。
cmdkey と net use pause は確認のために追加しています。
@echo off
cmdkey /list
if not "%~0"=="%~dp0.\%~nx0" start /min cmd /c,"%~dp0.\%~nx0" %* & goto :eof
net use D: \\Server01\sharefolder /USER:Server01\user01
net use
pause

なぜか2回起動したのでトリガーをログオン時 特定のユーザとしました。
最初のコンソールを表示しないためには wscript のようなWindowsプログラムから起動する必要があるようです。
例えば下記のようにします。
操作
プログラムの開始
プログラム／スクリプト wscript
引数の追加   "C:\Temp\startTaskBat.wsf" "C:\Temp\test.bat"
startTaskBat.wsfの例
<package>
  <job id="run">
    <script language="VBScript">
      Option Explicit
      '' 
      '' バッチファイルを起動する。
      '' このスクリプトを wscript で起動した時コンソールは表示されない。
      '' 引数はバッチファイルのパス。
      '' 
      Dim WshShell
      Dim strCommand
      '' WScript.Shell オブジェクトを作成する。
      Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      '' 引数のチェック
      if WScript.Arguments.length < 1 Then
        '' 引数なし
        WScript.Quit(1)
      End If
      '' 最初の引数はバッチファイルのパス
      strCommand = WScript.Arguments(0)
      '' バッチファイルを最小化・非アクティブで実行する
      WshShell.Run strCommand, 7, False
      WScript.Quit(0)
    </script>
  </job>
</package>

ご参考になれば幸いです。
